# Putting a Space between two characters on the Webpage through JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, space

I have a list which has options and no. of occurrences in front of it within brackets.

Something like this:-

```
Paris(12)
London(14)
Newyork(4)
```

I am hoping to put a space between letters and the first brace, so that each of the entries would be like :-

```
Paris (12)
London (14)
Newyork (4)
```

### HTML

```
<label class="option" for="ajax-facets-checkboxes-field-office-london">London(14) </label>
```

I actually don't know even if it's possible or not with Jquery. I'd be thankful for any assistance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest, using the anonymous function of the `text()` method:

```
$('label.option').text(function(i,t){
    return t.replace('(', ' (');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xPshn/).

The anonymous function exposes two parameters, the first is the index of the current element (the function iterates over the jQuery collection returned by the selector) amongst the collection, the second is the current text of the current element in that iteration.

With this function we change the text of the element, `t`, by replacing the `(` character with another string `(` (including a space prior to the parenthesis. Because we're only replacing one instance, we can use either a string *or* a regular expression to find the character we want to replace. To use a regular expression, however:

```
$('label.option').text(function(i,t){
    return t.replace(/\(/, ' (');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xPshn/1/).

References:

- [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: thanks a lot David. I tried this code within (function ($) { })(jQuery); but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: The demo I link to show that it does, in fact, work. Can you reproduce your problem in a similar [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Incidentally, "it doesn't work" tells me nothing about the error other than there *is* an error. What goes wrong? Are there any errors reported in your JavaScript console?

Comment: The problem was JQuery. I was supposed to put jQuery instead of $. Thanks a lot.